# How do I solve error with Active Directory Search using user name

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, search, active-directory

Im using the the below C# code to try search active directory for a user's email address by passing username. but this returns
error

```
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices;
public string GetADUserEmail(string userName)
{
    string domainpath = "LDAP://DC=domain,DC=local";
    DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(domainpath);
    DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
    search.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))", userName);
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
    StringBuilder userEmail = new StringBuilder();

    SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
    if (result != null)
    {
        int emailCount = result.Properties["mail"].Count;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < emailCount; counter++)
        {
            userEmail.Append((string)result.Properties["mail"][counter]);
        }
    }
    return userEmail.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Your format string doesn't contain any `{0}` to insert the username into the search query.

Comment: BTW, what is the concrete error message and which line produces it?

Comment: does not display any error message just "<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>"

Comment: the code is implemented as a webmethod in a webservices API, so when I invoke it using username it returns <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>

Comment: "_does not display any error_" If you run that code in a console application you would likely get a description of the error. That is the importance of creating a [mcve]... You get valuable information while doing it.

Answer (score 2):

That unkown error is likely because your pass arguments to [string.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2) without providing the correspondent placeholders in the string.

You must change the `Filter` to something similar to:

```
search.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(SAMAccountName={0}))", userName);
```

**Edit not related to your error**: If a user has more than one email address, your usage of the `StringBuilder` is wrong (lack of separator character).